# Resizing a folder of images and saving it with the same name in a different folder with opencv

Tags: python, path

Been trying to resize a folder of images (folder name here = Images) to a new folder named "Images_r" and saving the images with same name as the previous folder , but can't seem to be able to save them with the previos names .

```
inputFolder = 'Images'

for img in glob.glob(inputFolder + "/*.jpg"):
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    h = image
    imgResized = cv2.resize(image, (300, 400))
    cv2.imwrite('Images_r/image.jpg'  , imgResized)
```

This code is currently saving the resized images in the new folder as "image.jpg" I want it to be saved as the name it was in the previous folder automatically .

Comment: use imagemagick. OpenCV is for computer vision, not for recompressing some pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract file name from `img` and grab the last element, which is filename

```
import cv2
import os
import glob
inputFolder = 'Images'


for img in glob.glob(inputFolder + "/*.jpg"):
    image = cv2.imread(img)
    h = image
    imgResized = cv2.resize(image, (300, 400))
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('Images_r',img.split(os.sep)[-1]), imgResized)
```