# Why doesn't the shape predictor model "shape_predictor_68..." get included along the face_recognition library when building the executable?

Tags: python, cmake, pyinstaller, face-recognition, dlib

I've built an executable file using pyinstaller. I have tested my ".py" file it works perfectly through cmd and IDE but when I try in the exe file it shows an error.
The error :
RuntimeError: Unable to open C:\Users\Zahin\AppData\Local\Temp_MEI65562\face_recognition_models\models\shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat

I did a little bit of digging and found that face_recognition library doesn't include the shape predictor models when building an executable .

`

```
#importing libraries
import cv2
import glob
import requests
import face_recognition as fr

import numpy as np
import os
import csv
from csv import writer
import pickle




downloaded_images_folder = 'Images'
resized_images_folder = 'Images_r'
x = os.chdir(r"F:\This Semester\Python\Projects\Face Recognition")
binary_images = []
name_of_people = []
knownEncodedList = []

try:
    #Either you make a directory
    os.mkdir(os.path.join(x , resized_images_folder))
except:
    pass


#Resizing all images in main folder
'''https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74244841/resizing-a-
folder-of-images-and-saving-it-with-the-same-name-in-a-different-fold'''


p=1
for img in glob.glob(downloaded_images_folder + "/*.jpeg"):
    try :
        #First a amra downloaded image folder a dhuki
        #then one by one we resize the images
        #then savve them to resized image folder
        image = cv2.imread(img)
        h = image
        imgResized = cv2.resize(image, (300, 400))
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(resized_images_folder, img.split(os.sep)[-1]), imgResized)
        print("No. of image resized : " + str(p))
        p = p+1
    except:
        pass

try:
    #making a list of the names in resized images folder
    # os.listdir() :list of names of all the files present in the specified path
    list_of_names_in_resized_image_folder = os.listdir(resized_images_folder)
except:
    pass


q = 1
for jpg in list_of_names_in_resized_image_folder :
    #Ekta temporary list banailam
    x = []
    x.append(cv2.imread(f'{resized_images_folder}/{jpg}'))
    #Temporary list tai ekta binary image nilam
    #Ekhon amra oi temoporary list tai dhukbo
    #First kaj hocche facial encodings nawa jai naki check kora
    #Jodi encode kora jai then append the name of the person
    for img in x:
        try :
            y = []
            encode = np.array(fr.face_encodings(img)[0])
            knownEncodedList.append(encode)
            Data = encode
            name_of_people.append(os.path.splitext(jpg)[0])
            y.append(os.path.splitext(jpg)[0])
            Name  = str(y[0])

            print("No. of image encoded : " + str(q))
            q = q+1
        except :
            pass

pickle.dump(knownEncodedList , open("Face data" , "wb"))
pickle.dump(name_of_people , open("Name data" , "wb"))
print("done Pickling")

#import Face_recognition
```

`

I reinstalled pip , cmake , dlib , face recogniton , face_recogntion_models nothing seems to be working !

Comment: what command are you using to run pyinstaller?

Comment: @Alexander I used : pyinstaller home.py --onefile 
"home.py" is the main file which later on calls "Facial_Data.py"(the script posted here )
"home.py" runs properly but when i call "Facial_Data.py" it shows the above error
Here is the Git repository link : https://github.com/ZahinFyz/Face_Recognition

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for a few days i managed to find the solution .

so when we run the command :

> pyinstaller home.py --onefile "file-name.py"

in the cmd/terminal it makes 3 files "Build" , "dist" and "file-name.spec" . To solve this problem you'll need to run :

> pyi-makespec file-name.py

command in terminal . This will only make the spec "file-name.spec" file and not the exe file . After that you'll need to modify the spec file .

```
    # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['Vision.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[('F:\\This Semester\\Python\\Lib\\site-packages\\face_recognition_models', 'face_recognition_models')],
    datas=[('F:\\This Semester\\Python\\Projects\\Face Recognition\\giphy.gif', '.') , ('F:\\This Semester\\Python\\Projects\\Face Recognition\\temp2.png', '.') , ('F:\\This Semester\\Python\\Projects\\Face Recognition\\temp4.png', '.') , ('F:\\This Semester\\Python\\Projects\\Face Recognition\\eye.png', '.') ],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='Vision',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=['eye.ico'],
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='Vision',
)
```

In **binaries** you can add binary data first you'll give the path of the data you want to get then a "," after that
"**.**(for dist directory) or **folder name**(to story the imported data in that newly made folder in the dist directory)"
and in
**datas** you can add videos / gifs / images etc using the same format .

After the spec file has been modified run in cmd / Terminal :

> pyinstaller file-name.spec

This will make the exe file with the necessary files impported from their directories .
And the previous problem will not show anymore .